# Write multiple html files in Python using for loop

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Hi I am building a website using Python Flask.

I need to render about 5000 html page in the flask web that I build, and the way I do is below. 
So, my website is about stock market, and I want to render a html page for each company. My way of doing is to define each company page and render the same html file with different contents. In this way, I don't need to make 5,000 different html files, but I need to define 5,000 different @app.route as below. I wonder if there is any smarter way to do this.

```
@app.route('/analytics/signals/aapl')
def analytics_signals_aapl_page():
    all_ticker = full_list
    ticker_name = com_name
    ticker = 'AAPL'
    return render_template('company.html', all_ticker=all_ticker, ticker_name=ticker_name, ticker=ticker)

@app.route('/analytics/signals/ddf')
def analytics_signals_ddf_page():
    all_ticker = full_list
    ticker_name = com_name
    ticker = 'DDF'
    return render_template('company.html', all_ticker=all_ticker, ticker_name=ticker_name, ticker=ticker)

@app.route('/analytics/signals/aey')
def analytics_signals_aey_page():
    all_ticker = full_list
    ticker_name = com_name
    ticker = 'AEY'
    return render_template('company.html', all_ticker=all_ticker, ticker_name=ticker_name, ticker=ticker)
```

This is a part of company.html file where different contents are put based on the variables in the definition of each page in Python.

```
<section style="margin-top: 0px; background-color: #E6E6FA; padding: 0px; width:100%;">

        <div class="container">


                <h1 style="margin-top:10px; font-size: 25px;">{{ all_ticker[ticker_name[ticker]].split(':')[1] }} </h1>
                <p style="margin-top: -5px; margin-left: 2px; color:#9932CC; font-size: 10px;">Ticker: {{ all_ticker[ticker_name[ticker]].split(':')[0] }}, Sector: {{ all_ticker[ticker_name[ticker]].split(':')[2] }}, Industry: {{ all_ticker[ticker_name[ticker]].split(':')[3] }}</p>



        </div>
```

Let me know if you know any smarter way to do this. I appreciate it. Thanks!

Something that I have tried is below:

```
ticker_list = ['company1','company2','company3','company4','company5', ......'company5000']
for i in ticker_list:
    @app.route('analytics/signals/%s'.format(i))
    def analytics_signals_aapl_page():
        all_ticker = full_list
        ticker_name = com_name
        ticker = i
        return render_template('company.html', all_ticker=all_ticker, ticker_name=ticker_name, ticker=ticker)
```

It seems not to work though....
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, instead of making a route per ticker, consider parameterizing the route like:

```
@app.route('/analytics/signals/<ticker_url>')
def analytics_signals_aapl_page(ticker_url):
    all_ticker = full_list
    ticker_name = com_name
    ticker = ticker_url.upper()
    return render_template('company.html', all_ticker=all_ticker, ticker_name=ticker_name, ticker=ticker)
```

Other than that, why make a page per ticker? That forces your browser to re-render everything when you want to look at a different stock...

You could consider using a front-end framework like: [Google Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/), or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/). To bind your data dynamically to the page (*Front-End MVC model*)

If not you can still create a SPA (*single page application*) by using jQuery DOM manipulations and AJAX requests.

Comment: Thank you very much!! But in this case what is the "ticker_url" ? is it the list of ticker? or a single ticker like 'aapl' ? In this way, I still need to create 5,000 different definitions right? Can you explain more specifically please?

Comment: `ticker_url` is the `aapl` or `goog` or anything the user types after `/analytics/signals/...`. But NO you do not need anymore that this one route, since all stocks can now be referenced as `/analytics/signals/aapl` or `/analytics/signals/goog`, and it will render the page properly with the correct context

Comment: Oh, it worked. the first line should be @app.route('/analytics/signls/<ticker_url>') right? not just <ticker> Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It can be (I'll make the change). Glad it worked for you! Make sure to mark as accepted if this answer solved your issue